# vagrant error while loading shared libraries: libruby.so.2.4

Tags: arch-linux, vagrant, manjaro

I've run into an issue with `Vagrant` where it does not start and prints the following error:

```sh
➜  ~ vagrant
ruby: error while loading shared libraries: libruby.so.2.4: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Not sure what additional information to provide. So please feel free to ask and if possible provide guidance regarding how to gather the required information

Thanks beforehand!
Dippy

Answer (score 0):

Temporal fix, probably would bite me in the a** after major version of libruby.so
https://forum.manjaro.org/t/vagrant-failing-to-start-error-while-loading-shared-libraries-libruby-so-2-4/27386/14